# Compatibility of Legacy React Native Modules with New TurboModule Architecture

Tags: react-native, react-native-turbomodule

I am currently assessing the compatibility of older React Native modules with the new TurboModule architecture. Despite these modules not officially supporting TurboModule, I have attempted to build my application and it appears that both the legacy modules and those that do support TurboModule are functioning properly.

While the new TurboModule architecture offers improved performance and memory efficiency, there is uncertainty regarding the compatibility of older modules that were not explicitly designed to support TurboModule. The purpose of this issue is to gather insights and experiences from the community regarding the successful usage of legacy modules with the new architecture.

I have conducted preliminary tests and observed that the legacy modules seem to work as expected, alongside the TurboModule-supported ones. However, I would like to hear from others who have encountered similar scenarios. It would be valuable to understand any potential caveats, limitations, or specific steps taken to ensure the smooth functioning of these legacy modules within the new architecture.

If you have any relevant experiences, insights, or suggestions regarding the compatibility of legacy React Native modules with the new TurboModule architecture, please share them in the comments. Your contributions will help in assessing the feasibility of utilizing these legacy modules while leveraging the benefits of the TurboModule architecture. Thank you!